# Z-transform of a cosine without a unit step

Tags: z-transform

What is the $\mathcal Z$-transform of a cosine without a unit step, i.e. $x[n] = \cos(\omega_0 n)$ and not $x[n] = \cos(\omega_0n)u[n]$?

Comment: What have you tried and what are your own ideas about it? Asking this because that's a typical homework problem, and this site is not intended to provide solutions to homework problems. However, if you show your efforts, then you can expect some help.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal Z$-transform cannot exist for signals which doesn't have a common ROC because
$\cos(\omega n)$ can be written as 
$$\cos(\omega n)u(-n-1)+\cos(\omega n)u(n)$$

For $\cos(\omega n)u(-n-1 )$ part ROC is $|z|<1$ since it is left sided signal and for $\cos(\omega n)u(n)$ part ROC is $|z|>1$ since it is right sided signal. Therefore it does't have a common ROC hence $\mathcal Z$-transform is not possible. But $\mathcal Z$-transform for $a^{-|n|}\cos(\omega n)$ is possible, for $0<|a|<1 $ and ROC is $a<|z|<\frac 1a $.

Comment: I suppose you mean $e^{-|an|}\cos(\omega_0t)$, because otherwise the Z-transform doesn't exist either.

Comment: @MattL. Yeah I ment to add scaling factor so that the signal can have two sided spectrum thanks.